# How to delete every 10th node from singly linked list?

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm working on a study guide for an upcoming test and we need to be prepared to implement a weird function for linked lists to make sure we truly understand them.

We're supposed to make a method: void decimate(); that deletes every 10th node. However, when I print the list after calling decimate() the list remains unchanged. What am I missing?

```
    void decimate()
    {

        //iterate through the list
        //keep a counter
        //when counter is 10, remove that node

        temp = head;
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }
        prev = temp;
        prev->next = temp->next;
        delete temp;


    }
```

Comment: Kudos to your instructor for using the word "decimate" correctly. Anyway, what is `prev`?

Comment: This function only deletes the 10th node, not every 10th node. We need a definition of your list to be able to help you more.

Comment: @Clearer: it deletes the tenth node (or the eleventh, depending on what `head` is supposed to point to), but *leaves it in the list.* Yeah, this test is going to hurt.

Comment: @SteveHaigh: homework is not off topic. It's also weird that you choose to post an answer (psuedo-answer, really) and then vote to close.

Comment: I had a change of heart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify your method like below. You must always have a pointer who should point to the node to be deleted i.e. `team` here. Please see my below comments. They are very important.

```
 void decimate()
{

    //iterate through the list
    //keep a counter
    //when counter is 10, remove that node

    temp = head;
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        prev = temp;// this line of code should be here
        //prev is pointing to team and in below code temp is pointing to the next node
        temp = temp->next;
    }
            // here `prev->temp;` prev is pointing to temp
            prev->next = temp->next;// now prev is point to the node next to temp;
            //after the above code temp is detached from the list
            delete temp;
}
```

Now see below your mistakes:-

```
 prev = temp;// prev and temp both are pointing to the same node
 prev->next = temp->next;// wrong nothing going to happen
 delete temp; 
// if you make temp = NULL; here you will lost the rest of the list
```

Also delete actually do not destroy the memory area. It will be remain same. delete just mark that area as free for re-allocation/re-use only. That was the reason why even after the delete you can still see the whole list.

Comment: This worked. I understand what I did wrong so thank you so much :)

Comment: Sorry, didn't know I could do that. I'm pretty new to getting involved with the StackOverflow community.

Comment: @JoshGarza Welcome to SO. Please read this: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @JoshGarza, that is fine. I have added more information in my answer. Please read that as well. That will help you. Also please delete all the unnecessary comments.

Answer (score 3):

The second of these 2 lines does nothing:

`prev = temp;
   prev->next = temp->next;`

If you set `prev` to `temp` then `prev.next` is already `temp.next` is it not?

EDIT. So I got called out for a *pseudo answer*, I guess that's fair... You need to think about skipping the decimated node, you need to point to what the deleted item pointed to and not keep a reference to the one you deleted.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to assign prev to temp, instead of prev to previous of temp and then delete the temp. 
And your decimate() function is deleting the only 10th element, not every 10th element, so check if that is what expected.